# How to store results of an advanced search?

Tags: database, search, model, data-storage

Currently I am trying to add a new functionality to my system in which users will be able to see customs lists of products.

For the creation of these lists I will mostly likely use an algorithm or some criteria that will be used to gather data from my database, or sometimes use hand-picked items.

I wonder what is the best way to do that, in terms of storage and computational time. I was thinking about using an object for my model (something like `CustomList`), that will store some attributes regarding to this list (that is basically filled with products which are results of an advanced search in my database) and by doing so, store a query string or something like that so it can be reprocessed periodically and if it's personalized for an specific user, run it for every user that requests it.

**Example of a query (in natural language):** `"Select all items that are cheaper than 15 dollars and are designed for the gender of the user X"`

I don't know if there is a better way to do that. I wonder how *Spotify* work with their personalized and custom lists (like Discovery Weekly, Running Musics, Sleepy Monday et cetera).

Should I use a query string and store it on an attribute inside this object on my model? Should I do all of that without an object model (on the fly)? What are the best options? How big companies do that?